# How to determine the type of a property that depends on the type of another property of the same object

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

See example. I have type `TConfig`. I want to get suggestions of available fields in function parameter. This is example for working with redux store(reducer, state).

```
type TParam = any;

type TFunction = (param: TParam) => TParam;

type TConfig = Record<string, {func: TFunction, param: TParam}>;

function handleConfig(config: TConfig) {};


type TMyParam1 = {
  prop1: string;
  prop2: number;
}

type TMyParam2 = {
  prop3: boolean;
  prop4: string;
}

handleConfig({
  '1': {
    func: (param: TMyParam1) => param,
    param: {
      // I want suggestions of available fields in TMyParam1
    }
  },
  '2': {
    func: (param: TMyParam2) => param,
    param: {
      // I want suggestions of available fields in TMyParam2
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/wejkYN) meet your needs? If so I'll write an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for this to work, you need `handleConfig()` to be [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html). Conceptually, for each property key of the `config` input (`"1"` and `"2"` in your example), you want a single property value type that serves as both the type of the `param` property, and the input and output type of the `func` property (`TMyParam1` and `TMyParam2` in your example).  So let's make it generic in terms of an object type `T` corresponding to that shape (`{"1": TMyParam1; "2": TMyParam2}` in your example):

```
function handleConfig<T extends object>(config: { [K in keyof T]: {
    func: (param: T[K]) => T[K],
    param: T[K]
} }) { };
```

So `config`'s type is a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) over the properties of `T`.

This basic approach should work (you will get errors when and only when you make a mistake), but it seems you want to be able to get IntelliSense hints when `func` is specified but `param` is not.  And that means you want `T` to be inferred only from `func`, and then `param` is just *checked* against it, not *inferred* from it.  So you want to block inference on `param`, as described in [microsoft/TypeScript#14829](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14829).  The next release of TypeScript should include a native `NoInfer<T>` utility type, as implemented at [microsoft/TypeScript#56794](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/56794), at which point you can just write

```
function handleConfig<T extends object>(config: { [K in keyof T]: {
    func: (param: T[K]) => T[K],
    param: NoInfer<T[K]>
} }) { };
```

and things will behave as you expect:

```
handleConfig({
    '1': {
        func: (param: TMyParam1) => param,
        param: {
            // suggests prop1 and prop2
        }
    },
    '2': {
        func: (param: TMyParam2) => param,
        param: {
            // suggests prop3 and prop4
        }
    }
})
```

Until that release happens you can define your own `NoInfer` utility in a number of ways; here's one that works for this example:

```
type NoInfer<T> = T extends infer U ? U : never
```

(You can look at microsoft/TypeScript#14829 for this and other workarounds and explanations for how they work).

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAcg9gSQHYDMICcA8AVAfFAXimyggA9gIkATAZygEtUMoBVKAfjagC4okIANwwAoFAFckAY2AM4SKAAsAhjQA2EAMLyUDAOY5SFKnShwARgCsIM3AAopO-XwDeUANoBpRgoDWEEDgUYgBdVxEoSKgJaT47MGV0ZQBbPmwvEIBKQnx0zxCAGgiohKTU2ERmLDyQ-AB6OrN0KEtxWmBiDMZgwPEoankAcg7kpmooYEVoDHQ4ZvMIJj1SNVoIAHcp9AgRAF8oXey3XYBuEXPQSGIAWRAABUSUgEZCKBdiyLBZsCe+dvQlmcolAvnAwAAmPhIcTJBboM67C7gaDYW4PMrg17vYGgsAAZj45jgcA0qiBJW+ABY-sAAUg9Ajzip1FonHo7NiooMnoNwsDgTEpHFSik0mjHskntkCPgRckivyShK+Yr+Q0oLRxHo9BB2vRcS9VONceCPvzEcDdgqueDeW8zQLJEKoPFlTd7hLwdLZRLrYq5SrVVF1ZrtbrgPrvnioEaQVSHVELYm9pkgA)